# How to refer to next element in a loop?

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop, iterator

I've been looking around for this but can't find what I would like to. I'm sure I've seen this done before but I can't seem to find it. Here's an example:

In this case I would like to take the difference of each element in an array,

```
#Generate sample list
B = [a**2 for a in range(10)]
#Take difference of each element
C = [(b+1)-b for b in B]
```

the (b+1) is to denote the next element in the array which I don't know how to do and obviously doesn't work, giving the result:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

the result I would like is:

```
 [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17]
```

I understand that this result is shorter than the original array however the reason for this would be to replace ugly expressions such as:

```
 C = [B[i+1]-B[i] for i in range(len(B)-1)]
```

In this case it really isn't that bad at all, but there are cases that I need to iterate through multiple variables with long expressions and it gets annoying to keep having to write the index in each time. Right now I'm hoping that there is an easy pythonic way to do this that I don't know about...

EDIT: An example of what I mean about having to do this with multiple variables would be:

```
 X = [a for a in range(10)]
 Y = [a**2 for a in range(10)]
 Z = [a**3 for a in range(10)]

 for x,y,z in zip(X,Y,Z):
     x + (x+1) + (y-(y+1))/(z-(z+1))
```

where (x+1),(y+1),(z+1) denote the next element rather than:

```
 for i in range(len(X)):
     x[i] + x[i+1] + (y[i]-y[i+1])/(z[i]-z[i+1])
```

I am using python 2.7.5 btw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

re: your edit

`zip` is still the right solution.  You just need to zip together two iterators over the lists, the second of which should be advanced one tick.

```
from itertools import izip,tee

cur,nxt = tee(izip(X,Y,Z))

next(nxt,None) #advance nxt iterator

for (x1,y1,z1),(x2,y2,z2) in izip(cur,nxt):
    print x1 + x2 + (y1-y2)/(z1-z2)
```

If you don't like the inline `next` call, you can use `islice` like @FelixKling mentioned: `izip(cur,islice(nxt, 1, None))`.

Comment: on python version 2.7.5 this works with either zip or izip. I actually like this method a little bit more than the one @FelixKling mentioned but to each his own. Thanks!

Comment: @user2593236: To clarify some things: This is the same as my version, just applied to multiple lists. If that's your use case, of course you should go with this solution :) Regarding zip and izip: We recommended to use `izip` because in Python 2, `zip` process all arguments immediately and returns a new list. I.e. it basically creates a copy of all input lists, which is usually not desired. `izip` instead returns a generator, so that each "zipped" element is only generated when requested. Both work well in Python 2, they just work a little bit differently.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative you can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip), to create tuples of the current value, next value:

```
C = [b - a for a, b in zip(B, B[1:])]
```

I believe `zip` returns a generator in Python 3. In Python 2, you might want to use [`izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip). And `B[1:]`, you could use [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice): `islice(B, 1, None)`.

Comment: I use python 2.7 and I can confirm that the same approach as for python3 also works for python2

Comment: @sshashank124 these answers are good for one list but I'm looking for a more general way to do this that will allow for iteration through multiple lists while being able to refer to the next/previous element in each list maybe I should put an example in the question

Comment: You're correct about zip returning a generator in python3.  An alternative that I've started using is `from future_builtins import zip` rather than `itertools.izip`.  I think that version works on both python2.x and 3.x

Comment: @user2593236: Yeah, maybe you should. However if you have multiple lists, then `zip` might still good as solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want `enumerate`. As follows:

```
C = [B[b+1]-item for b,item in enumerate(B[:-1])]
```

or simply:

```
C = [B[b+1]-B[b] for b in range(len(B[:-1]))]
```

They both work.

#### Examples

```
>>> B = [a**2 for a in range(10)]
>>> C = [B[b+1]-item for b,item in enumerate(B[:-1])]

>>> print C
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty weird way, but it works!

```
b = [a**2 for a in range(10)]
print b
print reduce(lambda x, y:len(x) and x[:-1]+[y-x[-1], y] or [y], b, [])
```

I have created a bunk on CodeBunk so you can run the it too

http://codebunk.com/b/-JJzLIA-KZgASR_3a-I8